# Column 'latitude' does not exist when trying to retrieve video lat/long

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve the lat/long of a video selected using the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` intent.
I have the following code:

```
int data_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
int lat_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.LATITUDE);
int long_column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.LONGITUDE);
```

I'm getting this exception on the LATITUTDE/LONGITUDE column:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/video/media/1749 flg=0x1 }} to activity {}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **column 'latitude' does not exist**
```

I would love any feedback from someone who has experience retrieving the lat/long of a video/image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android uses a new constant called  `METADATA_KEY_LOCATION`  in `MediaMetadataRetriever` class to let apps access location information for images and videos. Link to docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

Example (not tested but pieced together):

```
 MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();  
 mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(_currentVideoFile.getAbsolutePath());  
 String location = mediaMetadataRetriever  
                .extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_LOCATION);
```

According to documentation this should give you lat/long as string `"-90.0000+180.0000"` as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#METADATA_KEY_LOCATION)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you go a step further and show how to parse `"-90.0000+180.0000"` to assign it to two variables `latitude` and `longitude` ?